# Django sqlite downgrade loaddata Could not load contenttypes.ContentType(pk=1): no such column: name

Tags: python, django, sqlite

i upgrade my django 1.6 installation to django 1.8. I had extended the user model and i was using south. When i made the migrations supidly i didnt realize that something was wrong with my models so i overrwritte 3 columns of my user model.

I had made a backup with dumbdata to a json file before upgrading to Django 1.6.

I dont know what to do to restore my db, so i first downgrade to django 1.6 (I dont know even if its necessary)

Then i try to load my backup  with loaddata (it was made befor upgrading to django 1.8) and i am getting this error:

```
 Could not load contenttypes.ContentType(pk=1): no such column: name
```

I check the documentation of contentypes:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType.name

"It says that Before Django 1.8, the name property was a real field on the ContentType model."

Im stuck, can someone give me an advice? How can i rename or create the field? 
Can i restore the entire db with my json file?

What would you do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your JSON fixture file to make it match the new state of the `ContentType` model.

I guess removing all the `name` keys from the JSON file will be enough.